# How can I add index on mongodb object type field in spring boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, indexing

This is collection "POST" with below fields.

```json
{
    "_id": {"$oid": ""},
    "content": "",
    "user": {
      "user_id": "12450",
      "user_type": "MENTOR",
      "nickname": "member member",
    },
    ...
}
```

And there is a entity class for this collection.

```kotlin
// kotlin
@Document(collection = "POST")
data class Post(

    @Id
    val postId: ObjectId?,

    @Field
    val content: String,

    @Field
    val user: UserProfile,

    ...
)

@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy::class)
class UserProfile(

    var userId: String,

    var userType: UserType,

    var nickname: String = "",
)
```

I want to create index on `user.user_id` field.

I thought of 2 ways of using annotation.

The first one is `@Indexed`.

```kotlin
@Field
@Indexed(name = "user.user_id")
val user: UserProfile,
```

But this one would use `user` field, not `user.user_id`.

So the next one is `@CompoundIndex`.

```kotlin
@CompoundIndex(
    name = "user.user_id_1",
    def = "{\"user.user_id_1\": 1}"
)
data class Post(
    @Field
    val user: UserProfile,
)
```

You can specify what field you want to use with this annotation.

Maybe I'm gonna use `@CompoundIndex` but if you have better idea, please let me know.
Thank you.